# Graphql Interfaces when using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, interface, graphql, graphiql

I am figuring my way around creating a GraphQL API using MongoDB and I am trying to get my head around interfaces.

I get the idea behind it and watched a bunch of videos on talks and howto's, but the one thing I am seeing is how to make the query resolver.

It is always displayed like this: `groups: () => { ... }`

`groups` would be listed in the query type, so it would need the mongodb query.

This is the resolver that I need to find the answer for:

**What goes inside of the `{...}` ?**

```
    Query: {
        groups: () => { ... },
        families: () => Family.find(),
        members: () => Member.find(),
    },
```

I think the area I am stuck in when it comes to the query is that: "What would the query be since `groups` is not a mongodb document?"

MORE INFORMATION:

Here is the full typedef

```
export const typeDefs = gql`

    interface Group {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
    }

    type Family implements Group {
        id: ID!
        name: String! # persons family name
        numberOfPeople: Int
    }

    type Member implements Group {
        id: ID!
        name: String! # persons first name
        age: Int!
    }

    type Query {
        groups: [Group]
        families: [Family]
        members: [Member]
    }
}
```

Here is the resolver

```
export const resolvers = {

    Group: {
        __resolveType(group, context, info){
          if(group.family){
            return 'Family';
          }
    
          if(group.member){
            return 'Member';
          }
    
          return null;
        },
      },

    Query: {
        groups: () => { ... },
        families: () => Family.find(),
        members: () => Member.find(),
    }
}
```

The idea is that `Family` and `Member` are separate documents which hold the data and that `Group` is the interface to create a query that combines them.

Answer (score 1):

edit: I re-readed your post and what you are trying to access here may not exist.
Because at the `__resolveType` you are validating against a schema property.

```
// Group:
     {
        __resolveType(group, context, info){
          if(group.family){ // property family is not defined in a group implementation.
            return 'Family';
          }
    
          if(group.member){
            return 'Member';
          }
    
          return null;
        },
      },
```

You may want to perform a validation against a **defined unique** property from an implementation either Family or Member like follows:

```
// Group:
     {
        __resolveType(group, context, info){
          if(group.numberOfPeople){
            return 'Family';
          }
    
          if(group.age){
            return 'Member';
          }
    
          return null;
        },
      },
```

Then when you query groups.

```
`
{
  groups {
    id
    name
    ... on Family {
      numberOfPeople 
    }
    ... on Member {
      age
    }
  }
}
`
```

[apollo docs reference](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/)

---

#### Get Automatically generated interfaces and typings.

I have found the best way to get typings for TS automatically from your schema using [graphql-code-generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/index). It has also a plugin to get [automatically generated mongoDB models](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-mongodb)

For a quick response paste your schema [here](https://graphql-code-generator.com/#live-demo).

---

**Quick setup for typescript:**

1. Install

`npm i -D @graphql-codegen/cli @graphql-codegen/typescript @graphql-codegen/typescript-resolvers`

It will install cli and typescript + typescript-resolvers plugins.

2. In your root create `codegen.yml` and put:

```yaml
overwrite: true
schema: 'http://localhost:3500/graphql'
generates:
  src/utils/codegen/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - 'typescript'
      - 'typescript-resolvers'
```

3. excecute command:

`graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml --watch src/**/*.ts`

4. Now you can do something as follows:

```
// Import the types of your generated ts file.
import { MutationResolvers, QueryResolvers, Resolvers } from '@/utils/codegen/graphql'

const Query: QueryResolvers = {
  players: () => players
}

const Mutation: MutationResolvers = {
  updatePlayer: () => player
}

const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  Query,
  Mutation
};
export default resolvers;
```

Screenshot examples:

[intellisense and autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvQ4a.png)

[proper validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKjI2.png)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes to this question - this is the code I had to put inside of the `Query{ ... }`

Effectively it is the function that executes the database query.

`Groups` is for a plural return,
`Group` is for a singular return

```
groups: async () => {

    let types = mongoose.modelNames()

    let total = []

    for(let t of types) {
        let temp = await mongoose.model(t).find()
        total.push(temp)
    }

    let flat = total.flat()

    return flat

},

group: (_, { id }) => {
    
    return mongoose.modelNames().map(async mn => {

        if (await mongoose.model(mn).exists({"_id": ObjectID(id)})) {
            return mongoose.model(mn).findOne({"_id": ObjectID(id)})
        } 

    })

},
```